# Make uWSGI use all workers

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

My application is very heavy (it downloads some data from internet and puts it into a zip file), and sometimes it takes even more than a minute to respond (please, note, this is a proof of concept). CPU has 2 cores and internet bandwidth is at 10% utilization during a request. I launch uWSGI like this:

```
uwsgi --processes=2 --http=:8001 --wsgi-file=app.py
```

When I start two requests, they queue up. How do I make them get handled simultaneously instead? Tried adding `--lazy`, `--master` and `--enable-threads` in all combinations, neither helped. Creating two separate instanced does work, but that doesn't seem like a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you are not trying to make two connections from the same browser (it is generally blocked) ? try with curl or wget

Comment: No, I'm not :) Thanks, wget worked. What is the rationale behind this blocking? Is there a way to suppress it? Because I can imagine a scenario when I would need more than one worker allocated to the same client.